# Running a python script for indefinite amount of time

Tags: python, anaconda

I create a python program to check if websites are down and storing information in txt file.  I have been running it on Anaconda command prompt but the program will eventually stop.  I am currently using a while loop where x = 1 to end it. I wanted to know if there is a better long running solution for this program.

Comment: Which platform ? Linux ? Check `crontab`

Comment: It is currently on Azure VM windows 10

Comment: What do you mean by "the program will eventually stop"? What happens? How does the program stop?